# Facebook has detected that proevent.am isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Tags: nginx, https, facebook-login

I have an application with django and what to add login feature with facebook but receive 'Facebook has detected that proevent.am isn't using a secure connection to transfer information'.

Https is already enabled in my website. All my requests to http are being redirected to https with nginx. I use certificates from Let's Encrypt.

```
upstream proevent {
server web:8000; ## change to lp_web_1:8000
}

upstream ws_server {
    server web:9000;
}

server {

listen 80;
server_name http_proevent;

location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

location /ws/ {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_ws;
   }

location @proxy_to_ws {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_redirect off;

       proxy_pass   http://ws_server;
   }


location /staticfiles/ {
    alias /usr/src/app/staticfiles/;
}

location /mediafiles/ {
    alias /usr/src/app/mediafiles/;
}

location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
allow all;
default_type text/plain;
root /var/www/certbot;
}

}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name https_proevent;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://proevent; #for demo purposes
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proevent.am/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proevent.am/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Until proevent.am updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log in to it.